# Google OAuth Sign In: redirect_uri_mismatch Error In iOS App

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, google-signin

I'm working on a react-native iOS app managed by expo.
I was following [this tutorial](https://blog.expo.io/google-sign-in-with-react-native-and-expo-9cac6c392f0e) to implement a google sign-in button. But I am getting a **redirect_uri_mismatch** error when the google sign in page is brought up.

This is really confusing since there is no option to add redirect URIs for an iOS app in the developer console.

[OAuth 2 Credentials Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN1Xx.png)

Do I need to add anything to my code?
Or do I need to create an OAuth client ID for a web app and somehow give it a deep link to the app as the redirect URI?

How can I fix this error?

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@alexwolski/google-sign-in-test)